# Stop containing button from handling input - Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, custom-controls

I'm working on a custom button where the content is sometimes a textbox. I'm doing this so I have a sort of edit-in-place where you can type text, hit enter, and then the textbox disappears and the button's text is what was typed.

So as a simple case, you could mock this up like so:

```
<Button>
    <TextBox />
</Button>
```

The problem is if you hit the <space> or <enter> while typing it'll "click" the button instead of input those keystrokes into the textbox.

Now, like I said, this is a custom button so I can do whatever I need to in the codebehind to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because a TextBox appears over a Button does not mean it should be *inside* the button :)

You are better off with a custom control that has a button with optional Textbox over it. That way the TextBox will not interfere with the button beahaviour. If you put them both in a grid you will still retain a lot of dynamic layout control.

You will just need to expose properties and events of the button (and probably of the TextBox) on your user control.

*If you need specific help, just ask.*

Comment: You know what? This is better for another reason too - I wanted the textbox to grow beyond the bounds of the button as the user typed. Sometimes it's the simplest thing you overlook! Thanks for the help.